# Connecting Java Web Application to Oracle Database

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, web, ibatis

```
<bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName"
                  value="????????????????????" />        
     <property name="url"
                  value="???????????????????????"/>
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>
```

I am not able to figure out what should go in driver class name value and url vale. I have downloaded Oracle sql developer and oracle 11 g.But i am not sure how to configure it to my java application

Comment: driverClassName should be "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" and the url should be "jdbc:oracle:thin:@<HOST>:1521:<SID>"

Answer (score 1):

Driver class name:- `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver`
URL :- `jdbc:oracle:thin:@(hostname):(port number):(database name)`

```
<bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName"
                  value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />        
     <property name="url"
                  value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@(hostname):(port number):(database name)"/>
        <property name="username" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
</bean>
```

Comment: As i am new to this,can u pls tel me which jars i need to install and if oracle sql developer is enough..and if we need oracle 11g

Answer (score 1):

Your qustion is not clear if you are using Spring framework there are two type of
Data source handling technique

**Method 1** you need to configure data source in your application server

```html
 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
  <property name="jndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/OracleDS" />
  <property name="cache" value="false"/>
     <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="false"/>
        <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
 </bean>
```

**Method 2**

```html
 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
   <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:OMQA" />
  <property name="username" value="root" />
  <property name="password" value="password" />
 </bean>
```

Comment: Hi. I am using Spring framework, So i want to know how can i configure oracle database . what jars and database i shd use

Comment: go to this link and dowload realated jar [link](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-112010-090769.html)

Comment: this online tutorial might be help to you [link]http://www.mkyong.com/spring/maven-spring-jdbc-example/